# Return second last date

Tags: r, datetime

```
> a
   UID Date.of.Txn
1    1  09-11-2016
2    1  25-10-2016
3    1  30-08-2016
4    2  30-08-2016
5    2  02-06-2016
6    3  18-04-2016
7    3  31-01-2016
8    4  03-11-2015
9    4  06-08-2015
10   5  20-05-2015
11   5  08-05-2015
```

What i want is that for every `UID` need to return second last date w.r.t. to its value in column `Date.of.Txn`.

For e.g

for 
`UID = 1` and `Date.of.Txn = 09-11-2016`

the last date of Txn on `09-11-2016` for `ID = 1` was `25-10-2016`
similarly for

`UID = 1` and `Date.of.Txn 25-10-2016` 
the last date of Txn on `25-10-2016` for `ID = 1` was `30-08-2016`

and

as there is no date available for 
`UID = 1` and `Date of Txn = 30-08-2016` 
the value in `Datesorted` column would be `0` as shown below .

```
> result
   UID Date.of.Txn Datesorted
1    1  09-11-2016 25-10-2016
2    1  25-10-2016 30-08-2016
3    1  30-08-2016          0
4    2  30-08-2016 02-06-2016
5    2  02-06-2016          0
6    3  18-04-2016 31-01-2016
7    3  31-01-2016          0
8    4  03-11-2015 06-08-2015
9    4  06-08-2015          0
10   5  20-05-2015 08-05-2015
11   5  08-05-2015          0
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: You can use dplyr and its lead/lag functions. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/window-functions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will also work (without changing the date format in the output):

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(a, a$UID), function(x){
   x <- x[order(as.Date(as.character(x$Date.of.Txn), format='%d-%m-%Y'), decreasing=TRUE),]
   x$Datesorted <- c(as.character(x$Date.of.Txn[2:nrow(x)]),'0')      
   x}))

     UID Date.of.Txn Datesorted
1.1    1  09-11-2016 25-10-2016
1.2    1  25-10-2016 30-08-2016
1.3    1  30-08-2016          0
2.4    2  30-08-2016 02-06-2016
2.5    2  02-06-2016          0
3.6    3  18-04-2016 31-01-2016
3.7    3  31-01-2016          0
4.8    4  03-11-2015 06-08-2015
4.9    4  06-08-2015          0
5.10   5  20-05-2015 08-05-2015
5.11   5  08-05-2015          0
```

Comment: Thanks Sandipan . Can you explain the code please ?

Comment: sure @pankaj. First we need split the data by UID, for each UID we shall have a data frame. Now sort each data frame w.r.t. time in decreasing order of time (if not already sorted) just to ensure that the date that appears first for any given UID is actually the last date (w.r.t. time). Then just we need to add a Datesorted column with the lagged version of the column Date.of.Txn with adding an additional zero.

Answer (score 0):

I gather that what is wanted is the prior date timewise within `UID` for each date.

Define a `prev_date` function which given a vector of dates finds the prior one for each (or NA if none).  Convert `Date.of.Txn` to `"Date"` class.  Finally apply `prev_date` by `UID` using `by`.  No packages are used.

```
prev_date <- function(d) {
   do.call("c", lapply(d, function(d0) if (any(d < d0)) max(d[d < d0]) else NA))
}

a2 <- transform(a, Date.of.Txn = as.Date(Date.of.Txn, "%d-%m-%Y"))
do.call("rbind", by(a2, a2$UID, transform, prev_date = prev_date(Date.of.Txn)))
```

The result is:

```
     UID Date.of.Txn  prev_date
1.1    1  2016-11-09 2016-10-25
1.2    1  2016-10-25 2016-08-30
1.3    1  2016-08-30       <NA>
2.4    2  2016-08-30 2016-06-02
2.5    2  2016-06-02       <NA>
3.6    3  2016-04-18 2016-01-31
3.7    3  2016-01-31       <NA>
4.8    4  2015-11-03 2015-08-06
4.9    4  2015-08-06       <NA>
5.10   5  2015-05-20 2015-05-08
5.11   5  2015-05-08       <NA>
```

**Note:** The input `a` in reproducible form (this should be provided in the question) is:

```
a <- structure(list(UID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L), Date.of.Txn = structure(c(5L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 
3L, 7L, 4L), .Label = c("02-06-2016", "03-11-2015", "06-08-2015", 
"08-05-2015", "09-11-2016", "18-04-2016", "20-05-2015", "25-10-2016", 
"30-08-2016", "31-01-2016"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("UID", 
"Date.of.Txn"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"))
```